# Defining a Javascript variable using data from a Foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<? foreach ($waiting_users as $waiting_user): ?>
<? echo $waiting_user->user_id; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

I need to define the user id in a javascript variable. What is the best way of doing something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user_id = "<? echo $waiting_user->user_id; ?>"; <-------------???
    var post_id = "<? echo $post_id; ?>";
</script>
```

EDIT

The foreach returns just one user id. It's used to display a user that has signed up for a chat. Then I use the code below which is in end.js to delete the user from a table. 
`DELETE FROM table WHERE user_id = ? AND post_id = ?;`

```
<a class="end" href="#" title="End">End</a>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.end").click(function() {

            $.post(base_url + "index.php/home/end", { user_id : user_id, post_id :         $(this).attr('id') }, function(data) 
            {
                    alert(data);                    
            }, "json");

             });


});
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this variable? Authentication? Just a listing of users?

Comment: The problem with this is that in the end only the last user is set into the variable.  The answer below from gion13 is good as it puts it into a JSON object that you can then work with all the users in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend getting the desired data through a service which you could call from javascript using ajax, but your version works too, although it is a bit messy.
If you really want to write php code that generates javascript code, I recommend you pass the whole object to the client side. Just make it a JSON and javascript will interpret it as a native javascript object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var users = <?php echo json_encode($waiting_user);?>;

    // do whatever you want to do with the users
    // ex :  iterate over all users
    for(var key in users)
    {
        var id = users[key].id;
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
If you only want to pass to the client side only the ids of the users, you should loop the users collection (in php) and store them in an array (or object). Then use the mechanism described above :

```
<?php
    $user_ids = [];
    foreach ($waiting_users as $waiting_user)
        $user_ids[] = $waiting_user->user_id;
?>
// ....
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user_ids = <?php echo json_encode($user_ids);?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you enclose a JSON object in quotes? Also.. closing quote?

Comment: This is not the solution. He wanted to get an array of the user IDs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a bit more information to my question.

Comment: @ciprian and what's the new problem?

Answer (score 0):

Collect the user ids in an array and then output that array as JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
$user_ids = array();
foreach($waiting_users as $u) {
  $user_ids[] = $u->user_id;
}
?>
var array_of_user_ids = <?=json_encode($user_ids)?>;
</script>
```